# Ruby array map(&:flatten) is causing a latency issue

Tags: ruby, performance

I have a multi-dimensional array as below

`arr = [["2", "3", "1"], ["5", "2", "6", "1", "4", "3"], ["2", "5", "1", "3", "6", "4"], ["2", "3", "1"], ["2", "3", "1"], ["1", "2", "3"]]`

I want to generate a combination and flatten it as below.

```
[["2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "1"], ["2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "2"], ["2", "5", "2", "2", "2", "3"], ["2", "5", "2", "2", "3", "1"], ["2", "5", "2", "2", "3", "2"], ["2", "5", "2", "2", "3", "3"],..., ["1", "3", "4", "1", "1", "3"]]
```

The code is as below

```
comb = arr.inject(&:product)
flat_arr = comb.map(&:flatten)
```

`flat_arr = comb.map(&:flatten)` is taking around `5ms-8ms`. I have many such arrays and it is causing a latency issue. Is there a way to reduce it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get rid of flattening altogether,

```
Benchmark.bm(7) do |bm|
  bm.report("inject") { n.times { arr.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten) }}
  bm.report("product splat") { n.times { arr[0].product(*arr[1..-1]) } }
end
                   user     system      total        real
inject         3.390163   0.003636   3.393799 (  3.397507)
product splat  0.514577   0.000000   0.514577 (  0.514595)
```

As

```
arr.inject(&:product).map(&:flatten) == arr[0].product(*arr[1..-1])
 => true
```

Comment: You saved me!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: A stylist difference only, but one could write, `arr.first.product *arr.drop(1)`,

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby#enumerablemaparrayflatten-vs-enumerableflat_map-code) GitHub is comparing I/O speed of several methods. Perhaps you might try that `flat_map` method to optimize your last operation.